# Python : Read the content from html tag

Tags: python

Im trying to read the content from my webpage, I want the content from particular tag,

For Example : `<div id="extension-id" class="bounded-text">ID: jljdfmfebppemoghjopapmnpedkibcpi</div>`

I can find the existence of this tag using the method driver.find_element_by_id, after this I want to get the id inside the tag i.e `jljdfmfebppemoghjopapmnpedkibcpi`.

I tried with bs4(beautiful soap), it gives me the whole page content.

Can anyone help me in getting the content from that tag.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using bs4 you can return do this:

```
element.encode_contents()
```

This returns the inner HTML of an element as a UTF-8 encoded bytestring.

Back in bs3 you could do:

```
element.renderContents()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get any elements contents using BS4
First Create an object

```
html = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
```

Then do.

```
html.find(id="MyId").text
```

This will give you the text on only that element.

Comment: what if the content contains html tags? This answer wont cut it

Comment: I will not return any tags .Returns only the text in between of those tags

Comment: so what if the element in question has html tag has between it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.You will understand it more if you try it yourself.

Comment: what if "MyId" element has html tags in it? thats what im asking u

Comment: Id This is the html
<html><myId>This is a <span>Simple explanation</span></myID></html>
output would be
This is a Simple explanation

Comment: what if the owner of the question needs the html tags..lets say it was a div

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: anyways its better to use `encode_contents()` check that..U welcome